# How bind color with data in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i need some help.
I am working on pie chart and need bind currency to accurate color
 I have perhaps this JSON

```
      [{'rate': 24, 'currency': 'EUR'},
        {'rate': 32, 'currency': 'USD'},
        {'rate': 13, 'currency': 'GB'}
       ];
```

and these array of colors:

```
 colors = ['red', 'green','blue'];
```

so in my d3 chart pie i want bind currency to right color, 
to EUR bind blue
to USD bind red
to GB bind green;

how can i do this ?

making pie chart's path code is:

```
 const color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(colors);  
 const path = chartSvg.selectAll('path')
                        .data(pie(data))
                        .enter()
                        .append('path')
                        .attr('d',arc)
                        .attr('fill',function(d,i){
                            return color(d.data.currency);
                        });
```

Comment: you can write a if block in the pie chart's fill ...can you post the code where you making pie chart's path

Comment: const path = chartSvg.selectAll('path')
                            .data(pie(data))
                            .enter()
                            .append('path')
                            .attr('d',arc)
                            .attr('fill',function(d,i){
                                return color(d.data.currency);
                            });

Comment: put an if block in the fill function to return the color  from the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way:

```
var colors = ['red', 'green','blue'];
const path = chartSvg.selectAll('path')
                        .data(pie(data))
                        .enter()
                        .append('path')
                        .attr('d',arc)
                        .attr('fill',function(d,i){
                            if (d.data.currency == "EUR")
                             return color[2];
                            if (d.data.currency == "USD")
                             return color[0];
                            if (d.data.currency == "GB")
                             return color[1];
                        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i is working and i understand it know.

Answer (score 1):

Although Cyrils answer works it can result in quite a lot of if-else-blocks. A different approach would be to use a ordinal scale like this:

```
var currencyScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(['EUR', 'USD'])
   .range(['red', 'blue']);

path.attr('fill',function(d){
  return currencyScale(d.data.currency);
});
```